# Can't set min_confidence in apriori

Tags: python, algorithm, apriori, mlxtend

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orLVm.png) In Python, I am performing Market Basket Analysis/Optimization using the Apriori Algorithm. When I try to set min confidence, this error message appears: apriori() received an unusual keyword argument 'min confidence'. I also attempted to use 'min threshold,' but received the same issue. I have also attached the screenshot for ease. I AM USING Kaggle Note Book

So I was trying to set rules for Apriori. When I am trying to set min_confidence, This error pops out apriori() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_confidence'.

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. Take a minute to check out [how to create minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the parameters are supposed to be named `minConfidence` and `minSupport`.

https://pypi.org/project/apriori-python/

Comment: Tried minConfidence and minSupport sill not working